# sapui5 opa5 opa script is not identifying View

Tags: sapui5

I have written an OPA Script but it was not identifying the View id's. Can you please help me to solve this?

OPA Script is not able to enter the text "Testing in Description" in the Text Area Field

My Script is getting failed and im seeing below Error.

```
There was no Input
Opa timeout
This is what Opa logged:
all results were filtered out by the matchers - skipping the check -  sap.ui.test.pipelines.MatcherPipeline
Callstack:
    at fillDescription (https://webidetesting7755399-w3446edba.dispatcher.int.sap.hana.ondemand.com/webapp/test/integration/pages/ActivitySet.js?eval:58:19)
    at Object.eval (https://webidetesting7755399-w3446edba.dispatcher.int.sap.hana.ondemand.com/webapp/test/integration/AllActivitySets.js?eval:32:30)
Expected:   
true
Result:     
false
Diff:   
trufalse
```

Below is my Code..

```
Opa5.extendConfig({
        viewName : "test",
        arrangements: new Common(),
        viewNamespace: "com.tools.melody.activityForm.view.",
        autoWait: true
    });

opaTest("Enter Description", function (Given, When, Then) {
            // Arrangements
            //Given.iStartMyApp();

            //Actions
            When.onTheActivitySetPage.fillDescription();
        });

fillDescription: function () {
                        return this.waitFor({
                            id:"activityFormDescription",
                            //controlType: "sap.m.TextArea",
                            actions: new EnterText({                            
                                text: "Testing in Description"
                            }),
                            success: function() {
                                Opa5.assert.ok(true, "Testing in Description");
                            },
                            errorMessage: "There was no Input"
                        });
                    },
```

View File ID ::

```
<TextArea id="activityFormDescription" value="{default>/0/Description}" change="handleChange"></TextArea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass viewName parameter to the waitFor function.

```
fillDescription: function () {
    return this.waitFor({
        id:"activityFormDescription",
        viewName : "test",
        actions: new EnterText({                            
            text: "Testing in Description"
        }),
        success: function() {
            Opa5.assert.ok(true, "Testing in Description");
        },
        errorMessage: "There was no Input"
    });
},
```

Comment: Thank you for your Answer, I have found the root cause of this. Actually i have resolved this issue by modifying manifest.json in Component.js..